# How to input Initial State in a table with boundary changes

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have a problem calculating sales in current month (working very slow), because i have a large table with sales for couple of years in it. So I find a solution to at the start of every month, calculating Initial state till 1st in the month, so for the sales on 14th in the month, just use sum between 1st and 14th (actual sales between this two dates + initial state). I also add a new column which will provide me information is it IS (initial state) or is it sales, so i can divide that two information.

The target table is zal_3b_orgjed

```
orgjed   |  date    |   rgrupa  |  sifra  |  velicina  |  quantity `| ISIS


 221       01-AUG-17    300       3000101      0             1
```

ISIS is not islamic state, it's acronym of IS initial state (for the record :))
This column has two state, D -is initial state, N-it is not initial state

I have query like this

```
     insert into zal_3b_orgjed



     select
           orgjed,to_date('01.01.2016','dd.mm.yyyy') as datum,rgrupa, sifra, 
           velicina,  sum(kolicina) , 'D'
    from 
          zal_3b_orgjedsavke 
    where 
          datum <= to_date('31.12.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')
          and sysdate > to_date('31.12.2015','dd.mm.yyyy')
    having 
          sum(kolicina) !=0  

    group by 
           orgjed, rgrupa, sifra, velicina

    union


    select 
           orgjed,to_date('01.02.2016','dd.mm.yyyy') as datum,rgrupa, sifra, 
           velicina,  sum(kolicina)  ,'D'
    from   
           zal_3b_orgjedsavke

    where 
          datum <= to_date('31.01.2016','dd.mm.yyyy')
          and sysdate > to_date('31.01.2016','dd.mm.yyyy')

   having 
          sum(kolicina) !=0 
   group by 
           orgjed, rgrupa, sifra, velicina
```

This is just a part of the unions, as You can see there is a lot of unions, and every 1st of the month i need to add one more union. Is it there a easy way to do that, not manually. I have some ideas, but not sure how to get union in loop.
Can some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a single query?

```
select orgjed, trunc(datum, 'MON') as datum, rgrupa, sifra, velicina,
       sum(kolicina), 'D'
from zal_3b_orgjedsavke 
group by trunc(datum, 'MON'), orgjed, rgrupa, sifra, velicina
having sum(kolicina) <> 0  ;
```

This simply truncates `datum` to the first of the month.

You may still want a `WHERE` clause if you want to restrict the date range.

Comment: It seems to easy to be truth :) As You can see above in my query, i need a Initial States for every month, will this do that? And what about previos years, will this also do for previous years?

Comment: @Smederevac . . . I see a reference to that in the first paragraph.  However, this is just a simplification of the code that you are using.  I'm sure you can do what you want with an aggregation query, though.

Comment: I test this on real examples, and have figure it out next: All sales in one month sum it on the 1st in the month, but i wrote above that i need on the first of the month sum from previous month. But this way of solving help me really

Comment: Gordon, is it possible to somehow manage, that sum from the first date in the table till the every 1st in the month. For example, 1st entry date in table is 01-MAY-2015, so what i need is, 1st to calculate all changes from 01-MAY-2015 till 1-MAY-2015 and to writte on 01- JUN-2015, than for 01-JUN-2015 to calculate sum from 1st date in the table till last day in JUN and so on. Is this possible?

Comment: You would use `add_month(trunc(datum, 'MON'), 1)` to get the next month.